# How can I run Xamarin.Forms in my project from it's source, so I can set breakpoints etc in Xamarin.Froms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to be able to run Xamarin.Forms from source so I can set breakpoints etc in it.  I want to do this primarily so I can see how things get called so I can better understand how it works in response to my use of it in my app. I don't want to do it in the final app, I'd just like to swap out the source version for the nuget package in the end. During development though I would like to see how it runs things to better understand how I can manipulate/override/implement different details.

So far I am close to getting it to compile with my project, but I get 2 build issues realated to `Xamarin.Forms.Conrols.Issues` I think they are just unit tests, but it stops the build.

> /Users/username/github/Xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Issues/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Issues.Shared/Bugzilla39636.xaml: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Xamarin.Forms.Controls)

And

> /Users/username/github/Xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Issues/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Issues.Shared/PlatformSpecifics_iOSTranslucentNavBarX.xaml: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Xamarin.Forms.Controls)

Maybe there is a better way to run it from source and have it integrate with a project and I am just missing it?

These are the projects I have added to my project in a Solution Folder:

[image: Visual Studio Mac Projects]

Maybe I am on the right path, maybe not. Currently I am **only** targeting *iOS* I have an *Android* project but I am not concerned with that at the moment, just trying to limit it to running on *iOS*. If that's an issue I can definitely change it. It shouldn't care about the *Android* parts if I am building for *iOS* only. Maybe it does?

**... LATER ...**

Ok tinkering some more I got it down to these packages:

[image]

When I right click on the solution folder and select: "Build Xamarin.Forms" the build succeeds. It only fails now with the following error when I try to build my app's Form's project:

> /Users/username/github/Xamarin/MyProject/App.xaml.cs(13,13): Error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (MyProject)

I get 51 errors whenever it references anything inside Xamarin.Forms or when it's trying to access a `x:Name` in some XAML from the code behind.

*Intellisense* sees the method as well, in this case `InitializeComponent` so at least that seems to know about it.

Comment: I would just remove that project from the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Here's how I did it:

Clone the `Xamarin.Forms`repo from github:

```
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms
```

The following applies to `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247`

`cd` into the newly cloned repo and checkout that tag corresponding to Xamarin Forms v2.3.4.247:

```sh
$ git clone git@github.com:xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.git
$ cd Xamarin.Forms
$ git checkout 2.3.4-2
```

Add these projects into your project. I placed them in a new solution folder within the project in `Visual Studio Mac`. I was only concerned with iOS. It would be similar for Android, just adding those specific libs. To figure how the dependencies I just opened the `Xamarin.Forms.sln` file and check each project's references.

1. `Xamarin.Forms.Platform`
2. `Xamarin.Forms.Core`
3. `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS`
4. `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml`
5. `Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks`
6. `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Xamlc`
7. `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Xamlg`

Next, update packages for `Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks` (`Mono.Cecil` is missing when you import this project. It has a little warning icon by it in the packages list UI)

Now `cd` to your project folder and copy the `.nu*` files from the `Xamarin.Forms` Repo:

```sh
$ ls -1

Xamarin.Forms
YourProject

$ cd YourProject
$ cp -r ../Xamarin.Forms/.nu* ./
```

Afterwards, in the following to `csproj`files (The forms project and the platform project):

- `YourProject/YourProject/YourProject.csproj`
- `YourProject/iOS/SourceTest.iOS.csproj`

file add the following `<Import>` at the bottom before `</Project>`:

```xml
<Import Project="..\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

Note this is referencing  the files we copied above.

Finally it's time to add the references in Visual Studio to both projects.

**Forms Project**

[image: Forms Project References]

**Platform Project**

[image: Platform Project References]

That's it. It should compile now and you can add breakpoints into Xamarin.Forms and see how things run. Be sure you added that `<Import>` node above to **ALL** `csproj` files using Xamarin.Forms. From the looks of it, It's responsible for triggering XamlC to process the XAML. When you install `Xamarin.Forms` from Nuget, it adds this for you.  Also be sure you have copied the `*.nu` files mentioned above to the root of your solution directory.

Remember, once you are done tinkering and you decide to install the Nuget Xamarin.Forms package, you may need to undo some of the changes you made above. For example, check the `csproj` files to be sure the `<Import>` is only from the package install.

In case you get compiler errors, check the Xamarin project references. Here are the individual Xamarin related inter-project dependencies that I used to generate the project reference list above.

#### Xamarin.Forms.Core

References

- `Xamarin.Forms.Platform`

#### Xamarin.Forms.Platform

References

- **None**

#### Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS

References

- `Xamarin.Forms.Core`

#### Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

References

- `Xamarin.Forms.Core`

#### Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Xamlc

References

- `Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks`

#### Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Xamlg

References

- `Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks`

#### Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks

References

- `Xamarin.Forms.Core`
- `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AJ Venturella's answer, you also need in 2022:

```xml
...
  <Import Project="..\..\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\..\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.props" />
  <Import Project="..\..\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.DefaultItems.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\..\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.DefaultItems.props" />
</Project>
```

Open `.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.nuspec` and check the content that targets "build". It's what's above.